# Get wordpress comments without trackbacks?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can get the wordpress comments list using `get_comments`.
For example:

```
$comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=10');
```

It returns the trackbacks also. Is it possible to get only human comments (without trackbacks etc)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe:

```
$comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=10&type=comment');
```

Check out the [documentation reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/), though in the case of [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) it's not particularly helpful.

Also, another possible syntax which I find cleaner, is that the above syntax is equivalent to:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'number' => 10,
    'type' => 'comment',
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

The `$args` array defines the constraints you want when getting the comments.